# Подскажите правильный триггер

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице с разными товарами есть фильтр.
Выбирается отметкой checkbox.
При отметке checkbox обновляется список товаров на странице в соответствии с отмеченным типом.
У каждого товара есть картинка, загружается таким кодом:

```
<span data-more-photo='photo.jpg' class='lazy' id='01_pict' style="background-image: url('photo1.jpg');">
</span>
```

Скрипт для класса "lazy":

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseout mouseover', '.nbCatalogSectionContainer, form.nbFilter__form', function() {
            $('.lazy').lazy({
                bind: "event",
            });
});
```

После отметки checkbox в фильтре на странице обновляется список товаров.
И картинки этих появившихся товаров загружаются после движения курсора мыши.

Нужна альтернатива этому:

```
on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseout mouseover')
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы картинки загружались автоматически после обновления списка товаров.
Без движения мыши.

Пример страницы:
https://p-td.ru/catalog/domashniy-tekstil/polotentsa/f/color-is-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/a/

Comment: Пробовали ставить триггер на чекбокс? Чтобы при изменении чербоксов загружались?

Comment: Пробовали сделать `checkbox.addEventListener('change',funct())` или `<input type="checkbox" onclick="funct();"/>` или использовать `MutationObserver`?

Comment: Наверное, на чекбокс не получится.

Логика такая:
Чекбоксы внутри формы, при отметке чекбокса данные формы сразу отправляются через ajax.
И формируется обновлённый список товаров.
И в этом обновлённом списке картинки со стилем "lazy" загружаются только после того, как пользователь двигает мышкой.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseout mouseover', '.test', function() {
  console.log("inside mouse event");
});
$('.test').mouseenter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">TEST TEST TEST</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но сейчас так и сделано.
А можно сделать, чтобы mouseenter работало на весь body и не слишком ли это плохо с точки зрения нагрузки и вообще?

Comment: @ТорговыйДомПетровский Я не понимаю, что Вы спрашиваете. Где так сделано?

Comment: Пример страницы в самом вопросе - там так сделано.